# How to remove hash parameters from url in ASP.NET controller in order to return to the root uri in an Angular.JS application?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an Angular.JS page inside of an ASP.NET MVC5 C# application, and I would like to remove the # and trailing path from the URL on a new page load or browser page refresh.

For example: `www.example.com/calculator#/step2` I would like it to go back to simply `www.example.com/calculator` on a page refresh.

The idea is that I need it to start them back at the beginning of the calculator form on a new page load or a browser page refresh. The reason being is that the form I created does not persist the data between page refreshes, so they would need to refill in the data from the beginning.

Whenever the page is reloaded, it does call my ASP.NET calculator controller, so my idea is that the server could reset the URL path?

Inside of my ASP.NET calculator controller, I've got:

```
public class CalculatorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Calculator
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // check for # sign and remove it and trailing path from URL.
        // or simply make the path "/calculator" every time.
        return View();
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I am new to Angular.JS so if there is an Angular.JS solution to this problem I would love to hear that as well.

Comment: The string after the hash in the URL is not sent to the server when requesting a page, so you can't use redirect rules like that. It's client-side only, you should handle that with angular.

Comment: Use a resolve in router that checks a service where you can track steps. If step 1 not completed in service do angular redirect to that step. Also might consider using localStorage so user doesn't have to start all over again

Comment: Thank you for the comments @davc86 and @charlietfl! I will look into localStorage, that sounds like it may work better than what I had in mind. Do you happen to have an example of the resolver in router that could redirect if a step is not completed?

Comment: Read up on `resolve` for whichever router you are using. A simple conditional with redirect in that resolve isn't difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the advice of the helpful comments posted, I've written a solution to my question. Like davcs86 said, the string after the hash can only be handled client-side.

Using Angular.JS and `resolve` like charlietfl suggested, this is what I came up with:

```
var myApp = angular.module("app-calculator", ["calculatorControls", "ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "termsController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/content/templates/termsView.html"
        });

        $routeProvider.when("/condition", {
            controller: "conditionController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "/content/templates/conditionView.html",
            resolve: {
                validate: function ($location, Data) {
                    if (!Data.terms) {
                        $location.path('/');
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

    });
```

Basically, I use the `resolve: { validate: ... }` section to check if my `Data.terms` field has been completed. If the value has not been set (in the case of a browser page refresh which resets the data), then it will send redirect back to the root page using `$location.path('/');`. Otherwise if the Data.terms has been set, then it will load the page requested.

Answer (score 0):

I also solved this issue by jquery.My link was [http://localhost:53209/HarcamaIslemleri?toastMesaj=true] and I want to do it as
[http://localhost:53209/HarcamaIslemleri?toastMesaj=false] when I refresh the page.

in jquery I wrote this code block and it worked for me, I hope this answer will be useful

```
     $(document).ready(function () {  
       
         const queryString = window.location.search;
         if (queryString) {
             const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
             const stepValue = urlParams.get('toastMesaj');
             if (stepValue == "true") {
                 toastr.warning('Successfully Added!');
                 window.history.replaceState(null, null, '?toastMesaj=' + false);
             }
  
         }
});
```